# d3.js - Dendrogram display adjusted to the tree diagram

Tags: d3.js, dendrogram

With `d3.js` I have created [d3 dendrograms](https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/dendrogram_basic.html) to visualize hierachicals relations between objects. Dimensions and margins of the graph are defined with fixed height and width values.

```
var width = 1000,
    height = 800,
    boxWidth = 150,
    boxHeight = 35,
    gap = {
        width: 50,
        height: 12
    },
    margin = {
        top: 16,
        right: 16,
        bottom: 16,
        left: 16
    },
    svg;
```

With a few relations, display is ok but with many relations it's doesn't fit, graph is 'cut' and I can't see the entire graph. How to set this width and height properties dynamically and adjusted to the size of the graph ?

An example with a correct display : [Codepen](https://codepen.io/Pives/pen/YzQZMoy)
[image: good_display]

An example with an incorrect display : [Codepen](https://codepen.io/Pives/pen/LYLWoEE)
[image: bad_display]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's work this out, you need to know the bounding box of your content first and then adjust the svg size. To do that, in this particular case, you only have to look at the boxes or nodes and can ignore the links.

With that in mind you can do the following after populating the `Nodes` in your `renderRelationshipGraph` function and return the calculated value:

```js
function renderRelationshipGraph(data) {

    // ...

    var bbox = Nodes.reduce(function (max, d)
    {
      var w = d.x + boxWidth;
      var h = d.y + boxHeight;
      if (w > max[0]) {max[0] = w}
      if (h > max[1]) {max[1] = h}
      
      return max                               
    }, [0,0])

    return bbox
}
```

then on the main code change use it to update height and width of the svg:

```js
svg = d3.select("#tree").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);
    
    svg.append("g");
    
    var bbox = renderRelationshipGraph(data);
      svg.attr("width", bbox[0])
      .attr("height", bbox[1]);
```

You can add a transition and limit the height but this does what you requested with a really large end result.

Comment: Order of instructions matter: when I create `var bbox` after populating the `Nodes`, `bbox[0]` and `bbox[1]` return me `0`. I only have calculated values when I place it after `renderRelationshipGraph(data);` Why do you define `var bbox` 2 times ? (before and after `renderRelationshipGraph(data);` ?

Comment: the first part is inside the function the second is out, I'll update to clarify that